# How to center JLabel and JButton in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, boxlayout

I want to create simple menu with difficult levels

[image: Screen shot]

Next few lines of code is constructor.

```
super();

setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

addButtons();
```

Method `addButtons()` add buttons which you can see on screenshoot:

```
add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

addLabel("<html>Current level <b>" + Game.instance()
                                         .getLevelString() +
         "</b></html>");

add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

addButton("Easy");

add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

addButton("Normal");

add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

addButton("Hard");

add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

addButton("Back");

add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

Method `addButton()`

```
private void addButton(String text)
{
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button.setFocusable(false);

    add(button);
}
```

And `addLabel()`

```
private void addLabel(String text)
{
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);

    add(label);
}
```

I don't know how to align all elements to center. It's problem for me. Additional problem is when I change difficult level text on `JLabel` can change into, for simple 'Current level EASY'. Then `JButtons` are moving a lot of pixels right and I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second parameter in the `public JLabel(String text, int horizontalAlignment)` is for determine the text position of the label. You need to set the `JLabel` component's aligment by `setAlignmentX` method.

```
private void addLabel(String text) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    add(label);
}
```

**Edit:**

Your second issue is weird. I don't know why this is happening but I think creating a second panel for buttons will solve your issue.

in constructor use border layout:

```
super();

//set size

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

addButtons();
```

`addButtons()` method:

```
//you can use empty border if you want add some insets to the top
//for example: setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 0, 0, 0));

addLabel("<html>Current level <b>" + Game.instance()
                                     .getLevelString() +
     "</b></html>");

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

buttonPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

buttonPanel.add(createButton("Easy"));

buttonPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

//Add all buttons

add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

`createButton()` method

```
private JButton createButton(String text)
{
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button.setFocusable(false);

    return button;
}
```

`addLabel()` method

```
private void addLabel(String text)
{
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);
    add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

Comment: Ok, it's working but when I change level (and text in `JLabel`) my buttons move some pixels to right edge.

Comment: setAlignmentX did the job for me too