# My swing arrangements is not clear when clicking the maximize button

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am a newbie to using Netbeans for Java Swing. I created a new `JFrame` form and just dragged a name label and text field to the frame.

[image]

**Now, the label and text field at the center side of my label.**
When I am Maximize the frame, the order (arrangements of `JLabel` and `JTextField`) will be changing.

[image]

What is the reason?

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering a JLabel in a JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829319/centering-a-jlabel-in-a-jpanel)

Comment: Consider adding a [Minimal, Complete and Verifable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: You really need to learn how to use Layout Mangers, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375255/jpanel-positions-and-sizes-changes-according-to-screensize

Comment: *"What is the reason?"* The code, which by the sounds of it, does **not** use layout managers (properly).

*"How can I solve it?"* **Use** layout managers (properly).

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are using NetBeans GUI builder. You need to edit
the gaps to the left and top of the two components.

[image: Matisse screenshot]

There need to be those strings on all the four sides.

[image: Matisse screenshot 2]

When you click on the shaded area, a window pops up. There you
can edit the type of the gap you have. By default, the gaps to the
left and top are not resizable. So click on the resizable check
button.

I recommend you to start learning Swing without using the GUI Builder.
In my opinion, it is the best way to learn Swing. Later, when you
already know something, you can start using the NetBeans GUI Builder.

Here are two Swing tutorials (The second one was created by yours truly):

[Oracle Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

[ZetCode Swing tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/)